# PocketSphinx few words not getting recognized

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

Hi I a building an app using pocketsphinx I was able to run the demo app following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JyCUzUBGg8) tutorial.

It works fine but it doesnt recognizes few words. Inside the project assests folder there is dialog.gram file which contains bunch of words that shud be recognized. I added two words hello and help.

Hello seemed to be recognized all the time but help it wasnt able to recognize even once.

Why is this?

I was searching on net and I came across making our own acoustic model but it seems to recognize other words fine except for few.

How shall I solve this problem?

Comment: Provide the project you created. You can archive it and share on dropbox.

Comment: here is the link of the project from the tutorial i was refering: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ac3bhjemym8acz/PocketSphin_Youtube.zip

Comment: I am following this tutorial to develop acoustic model http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt its very complex :P so far I was just able to create 20 .wav files. Are there any simpler tutorials to do this? preferably videos :) so that i can understand n follow correctly

Comment: You need to share your updated project, not the original project. Your updates were wrong, not the main project. As for adaptation tutorial, you do not need it.

Comment: i really dint do any updates on that project i just changed the dialog.gram file under asset/models folder .Here is the link to my project https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7gs5yks8lb8ft2/PocketSphin_Youtube.zip

Comment: In your dialog.gram file in assets I see you added the word hello but I don't see you added the word help. You simply didn't add it. Try to add it and the word will be recognized.

Comment: I actually did add it then I removed it, i was trying out other words. If possible could u run my project and see if those words are recognized. I think the results depends on our accent and pronounciation as well.

Comment: I run it and all the words are recognized. It has nothing to do with the accents. I'm not sure what your question is about then.

Comment: okay thanks a lot for ur help :) I really do appreciate it thanks :)

Comment: can u answer this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349508/error-in-converting-the-sendump-and-mdef-files-pocketsphins I was trying to adapt the default acoustic model but ran into some error and m not able to solve it